# Java: Multiple SSL connections simultaneously with independent SSL sessions

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, netty, jsse

I am simulating multiple end user devices connecting to a server simultaneously. The connections are made using HttpsUrlConnection and all the connections share the same SSLSession. What is the way to have independent SSLSessions for each of the HttpsUrlConnections?

I am testing the SSL Session Cache behavior of the server and hence need this capability.

I tried using a new instance of SSLSocketFactory for each HttpsUrlConnection instance but the SSL session id in the nginx logs on the server is the same for all.

```
url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
SimpleSSLSocketFactory sssf = new SimpleSSLSocketFactory();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sssf);
```

It is also not clear how to obtain the SSLSession instance for the HttpsUrlConnection instance.